# Why is the exe produced by PyInstaller failing this import?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput

I am having trouble with PyInstaller. I am trying to build the main file (`Logical.py -> Logical.exe`). When I run the file as a python script it runs fine (terminal: `python Logical.py examples/led.lgc`). When I run the exe built by PyInstaller (terminal: `./Logical examples/led.lgc`), I get this error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Logical.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[10688] Failed to execute script Logical
```

It appears to be upset about the `pynput` import, though I have no idea why. The imports of my source are below. `loading` and `ui` are both in the project directory and simpleANSI's source code is listed at the bottom of this post.

```py
import sys, time, os, ctypes
from pynput import keyboard
from loading.loading import loadElement
from ui import vec2, widget, ansiManager
import simpleANSI as ANSI
import pdb
```

I run both of these repositories so I can guarantee that they will not change until I can get this fixed.

- Full project source code - https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/Logical
- Main file - https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/Logical/blob/master/Logical.py.
- simpleANSI source code - https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/simpleANSI

I am using Python 3.9.5 on Windows 10 x64, PyInstaller version 4.3, pynput version 1.7.3.

EDIT: I dug through the Python lib files and found the destination of the traceback. This is the offending function in `...\python\3.9.5\Lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py`:

```py
def backend(package):
    """Returns the backend module for a package.

    :param str package: The package for which to load a backend.
    """
    backend_name = os.environ.get(
        'PYNPUT_BACKEND_{}'.format(package.rsplit('.')[-1].upper()),
        os.environ.get('PYNPUT_BACKEND', None))
    if backend_name:
        modules = [backend_name]
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
        modules = ['darwin']
    elif sys.platform == 'win32':
        modules = ['win32']
    else:
        modules = ['xorg']

    errors = []
    resolutions = []
    for module in modules:
        try:
            return importlib.import_module('._' + module, package)
        except ImportError as e:
            errors.append(e)
            if module in RESOLUTIONS:
                resolutions.append(RESOLUTIONS[module])

    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(    # AwesomeCronk: This is the offending line
        '; '.join(str(e) for e in errors)) + ('\n\n'
            'Try one of the following resolutions:\n\n'
            + '\n\n'.join(
                ' * {}'.format(s)
                for s in resolutions))
            if resolutions else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `--hidden-import "pynput.keyboard._win32" --hidden-import "pynput.mouse._win32"` to the PyInstaller args to no avail. I wound up rolling back pynput to version 1.6.8.